# Hide image caption on hover and show overlay text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

Hide image caption on hover and show overlay text: I have image which has title(caption) on it. What I'm trying to do now is when I hover over the image to remove the title and show other text (description).

The problem is that the title is hidden but also the other text.

Can someone point me where I'm wrong here?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.overlay').hide();
  $('.section-solution').hover(
    function() {
      $('.hide-on-hover').hide();
      $('.text').show();
    },

    function() {
      $('.hide-on-hover').show();
      $('.text').hide();
    }
  );

});
```

```css
.container-img {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

.wp-caption {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.fullwidth-img img {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.wp-caption img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.wp-caption-text {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 4em;
  font-weight: 700;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wp-caption-text p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 2em;
}

.container-img:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="section-solution ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container-img fullwidth-img" id="last">
        <figure class="wp-caption">
          <div class="demo">
            <img width="300" height="200" src="https://img.purch.com/w/660/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5saXZlc2NpZW5jZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzEwMC8zNDkvb3JpZ2luYWwvc2liZXJpYW4tdGlnZXIuanBn">
          </div>
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">
              <figcaption class="wp-caption-text on-hover">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</figcaption>
            </div>
          </div>
          <figcaption class="wp-caption-text">
            <p class="hide-on-hover">
              Lorem ipsum
            </p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

The fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/98j07g4k/1/

Comment: Hello, it's not really possible for someone to help you that much if you don't provide any source code and maybe some screenshots of the website.

Comment: Question updated. I don't know what's happen and why JS part and Jsfiddle was removed

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$('.overlay').hide();` from the code it will work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  
  $('.section-solution').hover(
    function() {
      $('.hide-on-hover').hide();
      $('.show_text').show();
    },

    function() {
      $('.hide-on-hover').show();
      $('.show_text').hide();
    }
  );

});
```

```css
.container-img {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}

.wp-caption {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.fullwidth-img img {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.wp-caption img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.wp-caption-text {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 4em;
    font-weight: 700;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wp-caption-text p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 2em;
}

.container-img:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-solution ">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
                    <div class="container-img fullwidth-img" id="last">
                        <figure class="wp-caption">
                            <div class="demo">
                                <img width="300" height="200" src="https://img.purch.com/w/660/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5saXZlc2NpZW5jZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzEwMC8zNDkvb3JpZ2luYWwvc2liZXJpYW4tdGlnZXIuanBn">
                            </div>
                            <div class="overlay">
                              <div class="text"><figcaption class="wp-caption-text on-hover"><p class="show_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></figcaption></div>
                            </div>                            
                            <figcaption class="wp-caption-text">
                              <p class="hide-on-hover">
                              Lorem ipsum
                              </p>
                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </div>                    
                       
</div>
</div>

</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, great. So simple mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Strange but when I hover over image all the title on all the images on the page are hide and on the hovered one I see the text.

Comment: Add p class after <figcaption class="wp-caption-text on-hover"> this it will solve your problem i guess and use this class to show hide

Comment: Both the title and the caption on hover are wrapped in `<p>`  already

Comment: Edited answer kindly check it and let me know

Comment: Still same. I have 5 images coming from database on the page. When I hover over the first one all images got titles hide.

Comment: I guess it is because they have same classes? But how can be avoided this?

Comment: You need to add the class on hover

Comment: Sorry but was `on-hover` till now?

Comment: Yes, and with foreach

Answer (score 1):

Swap your javascript file for this and I'll add comments in the code for understanding.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

        var trade = true; // variable that controls whether the mouse was on 
                          // top of the image and left.

        $('.overlay').hide();
            $('.section-solution').hover(
                function () {
                    if(trade) {
                      $('.hide-on-hover').html("test");
                      $('.text').show();
                      trade = false;
                    } else {
                        // Here I set new text that can be any text just 
                        // need pass to html.
                        $('.hide-on-hover').html("Lorem ipsum");
                      trade = true;
                    }
                }
            );

         });
```

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55358565/edit) some explanation to your answer

Comment: This doesn't work. It' change all images to show the text.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way is to hide the title through the CSS. You can remove the JS part also. Simply target class `hide-on-hover` in your CSS and add `display: none;`

Here is how would look like

```css
.container-img {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}

.wp-caption {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.fullwidth-img img {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.wp-caption img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.wp-caption-text {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 4em;
    font-weight: 700;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wp-caption-text p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 2em;
}

.container-img:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.container-img:hover .hide-on-hover {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-solution ">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
                    <div class="container-img fullwidth-img" id="last">
                        <figure class="wp-caption">
                            <div class="demo">
                                <img width="300" height="200" src="https://img.purch.com/w/660/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5saXZlc2NpZW5jZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzEwMC8zNDkvb3JpZ2luYWwvc2liZXJpYW4tdGlnZXIuanBn">
                            </div>
                            <div class="overlay">
                              <div class="text"><figcaption class="wp-caption-text on-hover"><p class="show_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></figcaption></div>
                            </div>                            
                            <figcaption class="wp-caption-text">
                              <p class="hide-on-hover">
                              Lorem ipsum
                              </p>
                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </div>                    
                       
</div>
</div>

</section>
```

Probably the simplest and fastest way which I can think of.